# Pass a variable to CURL (Firebase REST API)

Tags: json, shell, parsing, curl, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to develop a script that will run on router with OpenWRT. Right now I'm able to get the IP of the router. I just want to upload it to Firebase. If I do the following it get written into the database:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"IPv4": "192.168.1.1"}' \
  'https://name.firebaseio.com/Values.json'
```

What I want to do know is pass the IP value as an input:

```
var=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}');
curl -X PUT -d '{"IPv4": '"${var}"'}' \
      'https://name.firebaseio.com/Values.json'
```

If I run this i get a parsing error:

```
{
  "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curl` invocation will work if you put backslashes before the double quotes around `${var}`:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"IPv4": '\"${var}\"'}' \
      'https://name.firebaseio.com/Values.json'
```

Or better, just put the whole `-d` arg in double quotes, and use backslashed double quotes inside:

```
curl -X PUT -d "{\"IPv4\": \"${var}\"}" \
      'https://name.firebaseio.com/Values.json'
```

In contrast, the way it’s formatted in the question, the `var` value gets sent unquoted in your JSON:

```
$ curl --trace-ascii - -X PUT -d '{"IPv4": '"${var}"'}' \
      'https://name.firebaseio.com/Values.json'

== Info:   Trying 104.154.130.226...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to name.firebaseio.com (104.154.130.226) port 443 (#0)
== Info: TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
== Info: Server certificate: firebaseio.com
== Info: Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
== Info: Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
=> Send header, 163 bytes (0xa3)
0000: PUT /Values.json HTTP/1.1
001b: Host: name.firebaseio.com
0036: User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
004f: Accept: */*
005c: Content-Length: 25
0070: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00a1:
=> Send data, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: {"IPv4": 192.168.111.100}
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Without the quotes, that’s not a value type the JSON parser recognizes (not a string, not a number, not an object, not an array, not `true`/`false`, not `null`), so the parse fails.